# PlayFramework2: get static image with white space in name

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have problem in getting static image with space in name, if name without spaces all is working.

So, I am using `@routes.Assets.at()` to get static resources, and that method wil create http get like next `http://localhost:9000/assets/data/1/testImage.png` so that http url will load image but if I have  url like that `http://localhost:9000/assets/data/1/test%20Image.png` I will receive `404` http code.

So, Is someone had the same problem ? How to fix it **without renaming** names of files ?
Thanks

---

Code is next:
`<img src="@routes.Assets.at("/data/1/testImage.png")"/>` with out spaces and 
`<img src="@routes.Assets.at("/data/1/test Image.png")"/>` with space.

---

Re-tested from images folder the same problem.
I am using **play framework 2.1.1 for Java**

Comment: What's the exact code of the `@routes` call? I tested with `<img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/fav icon.png")" />` and it correctly loads the image. (there's a space in there but it's at the line break)

Comment: @Aerus I've edited my post and added code I am using for getting image and it is not working, retested on favicon problem the same http://localhost:9000/assets/images/fav%20icon.png not working but file there is, http://localhost:9000/assets/images/favicon.png working.

Comment: That's really really odd, I have the exact same code working in FF 21.0. Sadly I'm not a Play expert so I wouldn't know what causes this, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran across this myself; looks like it was fixed in 2.2:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1522